# 2018 Intel Mac mini with Bluetooth and Wi-Fi issues

Tags: mac-mini

I swapped out an aging iMac for a 2018 Intel Mac mini and am about to toss it in the trash due to the Wi-Fi and Bluetooth interference issues.  Both cut out more frequently than I can tolerate, and I don't know what to do about it. I don't have easy access to a wired port for internet, so Wi-Fi  is pretty critical.

Any tips? I have my mini on my desk, near speakers, near other stuff that may cause interference, but I've never had this issue with any computer in my life. It's clearly a poor design choice by Apple.

I'm willing to buy some Wi-Fi and/or Bluetooth dongle that I could connect to, etc, and it seems that with one turned off, the issues go away.

This is incredibly frustrating, and "move your computer very far away from anything" is not a solution.

Comment: Have you tried your new-to-you Mac mini in a location other than your desk? As this is an uncommon complaint, it also may be that there's something awry within the computer, or one or both of the electronics that control wifi and/or Bluetooth.

Comment: I have a 2018 Mac mini and use the wired port for internet. When the Mac returns from sleep, there is a significant delay before I can access the internet. So, I can state using the wired port is not much of a solution.

Comment: You might find some remedies at [this link](https://www.cultofmac.com/718687/fix-wi-fi-bluetooth-interference-mac/).